# Set ImageButton's visibility using Eval

Tags: asp.net

I am trying to set the ImageButton visible property.

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="img_DataDeleted" runat="server" Visible='<%# !Convert.ToBoolean(Eval("IsDeleted")) %>' CausesValidation="false" CommandName="Delete" OnClientClick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this record?');" Text="Delete" ImageUrl="~/Images/Delete_btn.gif" ToolTip="Delete this record" />
```

This works fine when the record is deleted

I am trying to add,

```
 && !Convert.ToBoolean(Eval("DataID" == '1'))
```

so if DataID is 1 I want the ImageButton to be invisible

(DataID data type is int)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 Visible='<%# !Convert.ToBoolean(Eval("IsDeleted")) &&  !(Convert.ToInt32(Eval("DataID")) == 1 ) %>'
```

This works

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
Visible='<%# !Convert.ToBoolean(Eval("IsDeleted")) && !(Eval("DataID") == 1) %>'
```

Comment: I get the error "Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'object' and 'int'"